# Where can I find a complete list of Windows Scheduler Status Codes?

Tags: windows, scheduler

I am having troubles with a task I added to the Windows Scheduler and now I am trying to debug it. It is returning status code 267011 (in Hex: 41303). Where can I find a complete reference describing the Status Codes of the Windows Scheduler?

Only thing I found until now, is [this document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558). But it does not provide enough information in my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, found it finally: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383604(VS.85).aspx